# Do I store times/dates in SQLite databases as unix or something else?

Tags: database, python-3.x, time, data-analysis

I'm learning to do a bit of data analysis, one of my experiments is to find the date of every popular Reddit post and to figure out which date was the most popular to post, what time is the most popular time to post, etc.

I'm also learning SQL and SQLite, so once I get my data, which consists of 'date', 'score', 'title', I want to put that into a table

Long story short, leave time as unix or convert it to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS?

Which would be better for retrieval and data analysis later?

Comment: The answer depends on how you plan to use your date information.  This would determine whether you use UNIX timestamps or dates.  By the way, in SQLite (but not other databases), dates are just stored as plain text, so you should _always_ store your dates in an ISO format in SQLite.  That is, use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and _not_ `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: I plan on doing something like "if score > X, return these items to me", or say "Find the average score across each date, return the date of the highest average", "for each date, find the item with the highest score, return some sort of best time to post for optimal score' etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use date information in future then use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

See this [Document](https://analytics4all.org/2016/05/24/sql-working-with-datetime-functions/)